# Send walking ETA (estimated time of arrival) from Android

Tags: android

I am looking for an Android application that allows me send my [ETA (estimated time of arrival)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimated_time_of_arrival) when walking to another user. If possible, with as many features as in [Waze](https://support.google.com/waze/answer/6083090?hl=en), which does the same for driving ETA, viz:

- gratis
- manage a list of friends
- I can see whether the other user received my ETA
- the ETA is continuously updated
- the other user can use Android or iOS
- the other user can see my current location
- I can favorite destinations

Answer (score 6):

I think you might be looking for [Glympse](https://www.glympse.com), which allows you to share your location, destination and ETA with individuals or groups that you have set up for a specified period of time.

- gratis **Yes**
- manage a list of friends **uses your contact list or you can set up groups**
- I can see whether the other user viewed my ETA **Yes**
- the ETA is continuously updated **Yes**
- the other user can use Android or iOS **Android, IOS & WinPhone** apps for sending - recipient can be using any of those **with or without** the software installed or can be using a **desktop PC and a web interface.**
- the other user can see my current location **Yes via the web interface**
- I can favorite destinations **I believe so**
- You can also **request** a glympse from others.

[image: Glympse screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click for larger variant)</sup>

*Glympse* can be found at the [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.glympse.android.glympse) and on [iTunes](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/glympse-share-gps-location/id330316698?mt=8).

Comment: Nice, looks great!

Comment: Beat me to it – I overslept #D So: no answer from me, but a +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pathshare](https://pathsha.re/)

It allows you to share your current location with a group of friends.

[image: pathshare] [image: more]

> Pathshare is a beautiful app that helps you share your path in realtime. It was designed to be simple to use and make realtime location sharing a safe experience. With Pathshare, you can easily setup a session with your friends and share your location for a defined period of time. You and only you are in control of for how long you want to be seen by other participants! And there is more: Pathshare will automatically stop sharing your location when the defined time expires. That’s safe and easy!

**Features**

- Free as in free cookies
- Available for [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.freshbits.pathshare) & [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pathshare-realtime-location/id799501728?mt=8)
- Share with a select group of friends with notifications when friends join/leave a sharing session
- Users don't need the app installed, can view your location from any mobile/desktop web browser

Comment: Thanks, fewer features than Glympse, but maybe more convenient if that's enough for the user.